# Install dummynet in ubuntu x64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux.
I try install Dummynet on my laptop. My laptop use Ubuntu 13.10 x64.
I am folowing this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1337587
But when I compile it, it have some error:

```
tiena2cva@tiena2cva-linux:~/Downloads/ipfw3-2012$ make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod'
Makefile:282:  
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod'
Makefile:282:  
make -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-20-generic/build V= M=`pwd` modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20-generic'
/home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/Makefile:282:  
CC [M]  /home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/ip_fw2.o
CC [M]  /home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/ip_fw_pfil.o
CC [M]  /home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/ip_fw_sockopt.o
CC [M]  /home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/ip_fw_dynamic.o
CC [M]  /home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/ip_fw_table.o
CC [M]  /home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/ip_fw_log.o
CC [M]  /home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/radix.o
CC [M]  /home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/in_cksum.o
CC [M]  /home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/ip_dummynet.o
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
/home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/ip_dummynet.c: In function ‘fsk_detach’:
/home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/ip_dummynet.c:638:19: error: argument to     ‘sizeof’ in ‘memset’ call is the same expression as the destination; did you mean to    dereference it? [-Werror=sizeof-pointer-memaccess]
bzero(fs, sizeof(fs)); /* safety */
           ^
/home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/missing.h:138:34: note: in definition of    macro ‘bzero’
#define bzero(s, n) memset(s, 0, n)
                          ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod/ip_dummynet.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20-generic'
make[1]: *** [kipfw] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tiena2cva/Downloads/ipfw3-2012/kipfw-mod'
make: *** [kipfw] Error 2
```

I need you help.
Thank you.

Comment: Same problem reported here, not a cross post, but if anyone figures this one out they can A that one too: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134057/installing-dummynet-on-linux-ubuntu

Comment: @slm In my question, I wrote: " I am folowing this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1337587". this post can't help me. It is not worked with OSx64.